# swagger-codegen react client - experimental syntax 'classProperties' error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, swagger, babeljs, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate as swagger `es6` client for my `react` application but I'm running into the following `babel` error:

```
SyntaxError: /path/to/petstore/src/ApiClient.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (231:33):
```

The steps I've taken to reach this point:

1. install `swagger-codegen@2` using homebrew
2. generate swagger client using `swagger-codegen generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l javascript -o ./petstore --additional-properties usePromises=true,useES6=true`
3. added to`import { PetApi } from '../../../../petstore/src';`

My application'ss `package.json` contains the following:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
        "ajv": "^6.10.2",
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "fuzzysort": "^1.1.4",
        "immutability-helper": "^3.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
        "normalizr": "^3.4.0",
        "prop-types-defined": "^15.6.0",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
        "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
        "redux-testkit": "^1.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "reselect": "^4.0.0",
        "superagent": "^5.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {}
```

My application's `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'
    ],
    plugins: [
        [
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
            {
                'loose': true
            }
        ]
    ]
};
```

I have also tried wiping my `node_modules` and reinstalling them with `yarn`

I have tried going through all the swagger generated files and changing class properties to functions, which leads me to another error:

```
TypeError: _petstore_src__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.PetApi.getPetByIdWithHttpInfo is not a function
```

when I attempt to run `PetApi.getPetByIdWithHttpInfo(1)`

Let me know if any extra information is required.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you invoking the application? I followed your steps and ran `yarn run test` with no errors.